# How to embed image or video in Outlook 2007 e-mail

Tags: html, image, email, outlook

I'd like to be able to embed an image or video in e-mails I send with Outlook 2007. I say "embed" because I don't want to paste the image itself, which could make the size of the e-mail very large. What I need is to be able to put an HTML tag in the e-mail and have it read as HTML, such as

```
<img src="http://ImageURL">
```

or

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/number" OtherParameters></iframe>
```

In Outlook, I have "Option > Format" set to HTML, so I figure there should be a way to include HTML tags. But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [figured it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61690842/how-to-insert-html-including-images-in-an-e-mail-in-outlook-2016/61690843#61690843) a year later. The trick is that the file to "Insert as Text" (as instructed in [Jorge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54870394/how-to-embed-image-or-video-in-outlook-2007-e-mail/54871095#54871095)) has to be a complete HTML file, including `<HTML>` and `<body>` tags. That tells to Outlook to interpret the file as HTML, and to not actually insert it as text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a link to an email message in outlook 2016 follow the steps given below

- In your message, select the text you want to change into a hyperlink.
- On the Message tab, click Hyperlink.
- In the Link box, type the address for the link.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking. I know how to add a link, which means I don't have to worry about how to add an anchor tag, `<a HRef="URL">text</a>`. My question is not how to insert a link, but how to insert an image or video, which presumably means inserting an `img` or `iframe` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Write the html file outside of outlook (VSCode, notepad, sublime etc..),and save.

Next, click on the "attach file" / "insert file" icon (paperclip). Then select the html file, but instead of clicking insert, select "Insert as Text" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gLah.png)

Comment: Do those instructions apply to Outlook 2007? I don't see "Insert as text". The "Insert" tab has a section "Include", which has "Attach file" (paper clip), "Attach item", and some other options. The only "as text" is under "Attach item", but that seems to only allow for selecting an item from within Outlook, not a file. Am I missing something?

Comment: Okay, just a minute, I found "Insert as text". I was looking for it in the Outlook menu, but it's in the "Insert File" dialog box (obtained by clicking the "Attach File" button in the Outlook menu), in the drop-down of the "Insert" button. But when I do that with the HTML file, it just inserts the text of the file into the e-mail. It does not interpret it as HTML. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It works on Outlook 2016.  Perhaps the editor won't interpret the HTML.What happens if you send yourself the email after attaching the HTML as text?

Comment: Okay, I tried that experiment with an `iframe` tag. It did not work. In the received e-mail, the URL inside the tag was converted to a link, but the `iframe` tag remained as text. (The text file that I had inserted consisted of just that one tag. It did not include an `html` tag or `body` tag or anything else. Is that what you insert -- a `.htm` file containing just a single tag, which gets interpreted as HTML as soon as you insert it?)

Comment: I found this reference (https://www.outlook-apps.com/html-ignored-by-outlook/) that says Outlook ignores `iframe` tags. So I tried your method with just an `img` tag, and it still rendered as text, not as an image.

Comment: Interesting, this article on the same page says it can do some html with special templates,  a macro script, or with the use of the Word object library enabled (https://www.outlook-apps.com/insert-html-to-outlook-emails/)  but it is for Outlook 2013 I don't have a way of testing.